# "Stack Exchange  Internet Services Inc." or "Stack Exchange Inc."?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange

The [Careers TOS says Stack Exchange Internet Services Inc.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/terms-of-service), isn't the official name of the company **Stack Exchange Inc.**?

[image: SEIS]

[image: SEI]

<sub><sup>[This all comes from comments here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128818/bounties-on-meta-to-attract-stack-exchange-employee-attention#comment351823_128818)</sup></sub>

Comment: It used to be [Stack Overflow Internet Services](http://web.archive.org/web/20110301193635/http://stackoverflow.com/); I imagine at some point it was temporarily Stack Exchange Internet Services on the way to becoming Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: "Internet Services"!? Terrible name, glad they didn't keep it.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Oddly enough, if you go to the [legal page](http://web.archive.org/web/20110501134113/http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) in the web archive it still says the company name is _Stack Exchange Inc._, or maybe I'm misunderstanding how it works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official legal name of the company is "**Stack Exchange Inc.**"

When we were originally just Stack Overflow, there was already a company called Stack Overflow Inc, so we had to call the company "Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc."

When we [changed our name to Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/), we could become, simply, *Stack Exchange Inc.* The Careers reference was simply mistranslated from the original, longer name. The oversight is being corrected now. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The company used to be called "Stack Overflow Internet Services" and [was renamed to just "Stack Exchange" in 2011](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/).

The "Stack Exchange Internet Services Inc." looks like the result of an incomplete search & replace.