# Why would someone signing up for Travel want to subscribe to news from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, email, sign-up

I just happened to notice this checkbox option in the sign-up page on Travel:

[image: Travel Sign-Up Page]

It seems odd to have an option to sign up for Stack Overflow emails when the site has nothing to do with Stack Overflow. A first time user might not even know what Stack Overflow is. Shouldn't this be replaced with Stack Exchange?

Comment: Stack Overflow is the official company brand.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh, I always thought it was Stack Exchange and every site under it is its own thing. But I do know it started as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of September 2015, Stack Exchange, Inc. [rebranded itself as Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) as part of a broader business refocusing.

The "Stack Overflow" you see refers to the company "Stack Overflow" (Stack Exchange, Inc. d/b/a Stack Overflow).

Personally, I find this confusing, because the same name is used for both the company and the flagship site. For this reason, I generally refer to them using their legal name rather than their brand name.

<sub>Side note: part of why Stack Exchange, Inc. kept its existing legal name rather than change it was because there's another company with that name in New York state. For this reason, in its early years, it [was named Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128835/377214)</sub>

Comment: Wait, the rebrand was from SE to SO?

Comment: This is so confusing. It's like as if you could buy a Corolla from the Toyota Network, but then find out that the Toyota Network is actually The Corolla Company and that people who bought Camrys are still Corolla customers.

Comment: I agree, this is confusing to me too. Especially because Stack Overflow isn't really mentioned on any of the SE sites. Except (I just noticed) under the Company heading in the footer. But it also has a "Stack Exchange" copyright notice in the footer and the url is travel.stackexchange.com instead of travel.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @KodosJohnson The copyright notice uses the legal name, "Stack Exchange, Inc.".

Comment: I learned something new today! Might this confusion between brand name and the flagship site be partially responsible for the huge number of off-topic questions Meta receives daily?

Comment: Unlikely, @Mari-Lou. The programming Q&A site was never called "Stack Exchange". Stack Overflow has taught us many things, not the least of which is the maxim: "if there's a textbox somewhere on the Internet, someone will type a programming question into it".