# Did Prosus acquire just Stack Overflow or the whole Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, business-model

I'm asking you guys since I can't find relevant info. Google says that the parent company of Stack Exchange Network is Prosus. Wikipedia says that Prosus only owns Stack Overflow. This is confusing. Someone please clear me out. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, note that, regarding Prosus' purchase, [Catija's comment](/questions/365050/what-does-the-recent-sale-of-stack-exchange-mean-for-the-community/366113#comment1218433_365050) states ""Stack Overflow" is the publicly-used name of the company - the entire company was purchased, not only stackoverflow.com".

Comment: Stack Overflow is the name the company does business under and stack exchange inc is the name of the company legally. Think how Indiana Jones and Henry Jones Jr are the same person 

Comment: Oh, thanks John Omieland and Journeyman Geek. I hope Prosus or Naspers won't touch the current model of our beloved network.

Comment: So far they've been alright.

Answer (score 4):

Well, take a seat. A comfy one.

Back in the old days, the company was called Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc. (They could not call themselves "Stack Overflow, Inc." because [another company with that name already existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128835/152859).)

*Then* it was renamed Stack Exchange, Inc., but since the Stack Overflow brand was deemed more marketable, they [later switched to doing business as Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow) (while [still retaining the same legal name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270038/377214)).

Prosus bought over Stack Exchange, Inc. as a whole. The relationship between Stack Overflow (the company) and Stack Exchange, Inc. is the same as Indiana Jones and Henry Jones, Jr. or Batman and Bruce Wayne. They're the same entity under different names.