# Make the questions with bounties on meta(s) more visible to SE staff of SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bounties on meta to attract Stack Exchange employee attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128818/bounties-on-meta-to-attract-stack-exchange-employee-attention)

How do you like the idea of making the questions with bounties on meta more visible to the mods?

**Why?**

Because meta-questions with bounties are generally stuff like feature-requests, retag-requests and other stuff like that. SE staff can mostly do what the asker requested.

So, what do you think?

Comment: I tend to disagree: most questions with bounties are feature requests that mods can *not* fulfill. Look for example at the 17 featured questions on Meta.SO right now - I think none of them is addressing a mod

Comment: @pekka maybe only diamond mods

Comment: `Can this also be made into per-site metas?` No bounties or reputation on per site Metas.

Comment: @YannisRizos Sorry, I did not know that.

Comment: How would this be more useful than the *featured* tab?

Comment: Diamond mods _are_ the only mods. The stuff Pekka is talking about can only be done by members of the Stack Exchange development team.

Comment: Adding to what @TartLevee said, _moderator_, and _diamond moderator_ are normally the terms used for _community moderators_, who are not part of the Stack Exchange staff. Also members of the Stack Exchange staff have a diamond, but they can do things a community moderator cannot do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in my answer to [Bounties on meta to attract Stack Exchange employee attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128818/bounties-on-meta-to-attract-stack-exchange-employee-attention),

> When you offer a bounty on a Meta request, don't do it to attract *us*. Offer a bounty to attract *discussion*.

Don't think of bounties on feature requests as a sort of "paying" with rep to have your pet feature implemented. That's not how it works.

Instead, think of it as a way to encourage a larger group of people to consider the suggestion and publicise their thoughts, as a way to help those people in power to implement said suggestion to make an informed descision.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Nobody should think "I offered a bounty, and the feature must be implemented."

Comment: That's not what the OP asked though. He asked about making the right people *aware* of the requests... not that it matters, though, the point is clear enough.

Answer (score 9):

Most Meta questions with bounties are feature requests that mods can not fulfill. Look for example at the [17 featured questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) on Meta.SO right now - I think none of them is addressing a moderator, diamond or otherwise.

The only people who can do something about feature requests are the Stack Exchange team - and you can assume that they already frequently scan the "featured" list, or if they have trouble following it, they will build something to address the problem. It's not something that's in the community's control - nor should it be really.

Answer (score 3):

They already appear on the "Featured" tab. How much more "visible" do you want them to be? Frankly, I think the Moderators have enough to do without *another* queue to check.